# input tag (type=submit) not working as a link

Tags: html, tags

I tried this html code

```
<a href="error.html"> <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" /> </a>
```

It is a part of my html form.
I want to use submit button to submit the data and show ( error.html ) page.

Comment: What does 'working as link' mean? How should a *submit* button 'link'?

Comment: You cannot wrap input with link <a></a>

Answer (score 0):

You will wrap it with `<form action="error.html"></form>`

Comment: i am using that (action=" " ) for my php script.. can i do both simultaneouly

Comment: i want , when i click submit button , it should run a php script as well as load another page !

Comment: <form id="formLogin" action="signIn.php" method="post">
 
Username<input type="text" class="formText" name="username"/> <br/> Password <input type="password" class="formText" name="password"/> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
 </form>

Comment: Only with html, you cannot do what you want. But you can do it with php. In signIn.php you can add 
header('Location: error.html');
exit;
when you see it is error

Comment: actually i want to load error.html and run the complete script, both every time. that won't be possible with your suggested method !

Comment: I can not understand you :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```html
<html>
<form action="error.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button"> </input>
</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure of what you want to do, since you say you already have a `form` then I guess that the `error.html` is not calling to the `form` because you already have another link to the form already. Then this is could be a way to call on two pages almost at the same time. Submit first to the form and then after the sumbit it goes to the linked error page.

**Working to call on BOTH the form html and the error.html link:**

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
/** Delay me BEGIN **/
function DelayMyError(){
  var count = 0;
  // delay in milliseconds
  var delay = 100;

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (count++ < 1) {
        window.location.href='error.html';
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }, delay);
}
/** Delay me END **/
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="YourFormPage.html">
<input type="button" onclick="form.submit();DelayMyError();" value="Login"></input>
</form>
```

I hope this was the answer you were searching for. Please contact me back if it worked, I am curious too. Theoretically speaking it should work that it first submits and then after 100 milliseconds it calls for the link called `error.html`.

How ever if you just want to do a link without a delay you could do it like this, but there is a risk that this more simple approach will not call on the form and that it will only work as a link skipping the submit:

**OPTIONAL but I am unsure if this one will call on both the form html and the error.html or not:**

```
<form action="YourFormPage.html">
<input type="button" onclick="form.submit();window.location.href='error.html';" value="Login"></input>
</form>
```